# DeprecationWarning: info is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0

Tags: networkx

I am using `Networkx 2.8.4` and I started to get this `DeprecationWarning` when running `nx.info(G)`:

`DeprecationWarning: info is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0`

I could not find additional information online.
How are they replacing this command?
How to check the graph type otherwise?

The deprecation is not even listed in the [official list](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/developer/deprecations.html) (!!!).

Thank you!

`import networkx as nx`
`G = pd.read_pajek(path)`
`print(nx.info(G))`

Expected Output:
`MultiDiGraph with 11394 nodes and 40859 edges`

Comment: You can check if a graph is a `MultiDiGraph` with `isinstance(G, nx.MultiDiGraph)` (as you would with any other python class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was digging into the networkx code changes and found out you can just `print(G)` to get the expected output